# BulkWrite dynamic documents in MongoDB with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, mongodb

First post after 15 years of lurking. I'll be very grateful for any help.
My needs are simple: consume JSON data, upsert into mongodb. There are many records, and this process will be repeated over and over, so it seems like BulkWrite is what I want. The id of the record will remain constant, all other fields will need to be upserted during each run (for example, days_employed will update frequently). VB is a must.

My code so far is as follows:

```
Dim client As MongoClient
Dim db As IMongoDatabase

client = New MongoClient("mongodb://localhost/")
db = client.GetDatabase("db")


Dim collection As IMongoCollection(Of BsonDocument) = db.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("employees")

Dim documents As New List(Of BsonDocument)

''CREATE 10 documents to insert into the collection
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
For i As Integer = 1 To 10
    Dim emp As BsonDocument = New BsonDocument
    With emp
        .Add("_id", "x" & i) 'Guid.NewGuid().ToString)
        .Add("name", "George Jones")
        .Add("first_name", "George")
        .Add("days_employed", "24")
        .Add("job_desc", "Coder")
        .Add("location", "Istanbul")
    End With
    documents.Add(emp)
Next

'bulkwrite documents into collection
collection.BulkWrite(documents.[Select](Function(d) New InsertOneModel(Of BsonDocument)(d)))
```

But as you can see, this simply inserts, it doesn't upsert. I think I need to use UpdateOneModel instead of InsertOneModel, but UpdateOneModel takes filter and update parameters. I cannot figure out how to dynamically create the update parameter. Every example I find hard-codes the update value into the example, but in my case, that data is coming from another source. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I have been unclear, I apologize, and will try to clarify if needed. If there is another entirely different way of accomplishing this same task, I am very open to that as well. I am coming from SQL Server, which I find much simpler, but need to process large amounts of data (millions of records daily) and would like to see if there is a performance improvement with mongodb. There aren't many .NET code examples, and almost zero VB samples.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Added an example of the JSON as it will be consumed:

```
{
  "name": "George Jones",
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "days_employed": 28,
  "appointments": {
    "2020-03-12:0": {
      "2pm": [
        {
          "apptWith": "Alex Thompson",
          "MaxLength": 90,
          "description": "Product Development",
          "meetingLocation": "New York"
        }
      ],
      "4pm": [
        {
          "apptWith": "Paul Jones",
          "MaxLength": 60,
          "description": "Accounting",
          "meetingLocation": "New York"
        }
      ]
    },
    "2020-03-14:7": {
      "1130am": [
        {
          "apptWith": "Mike Rogers",
          "MaxLength": 90,
          "description": "Product Development",
          "meetingLocation": "San Diego"
        }
      ],
      "230pm": [
        {
          "apptWith": "Felix Henderson",
          "MaxLength": 30,
          "description": "Accounting",
          "meetingLocation": "San Diego"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "appointmentRequests": {
    "2020-03-10:0": {
      "8am": [
        {
          "apptWith": "Jose Guitierez",
          "MaxLength": 60,
          "description": "Product Launch",
          "meetingLocation": "Orlando"
        }
      ],
      "3pm": [
        {
          "apptWith": "Ronald Clubman",
          "MaxLength": 60,
          "description": "Marketing",
          "meetingLocation": "New York"
        }
      ]
    },
    "2020-03-11:7": {
      "1130am": [
        {
          "apptWith": "Phil Norton",
          "MaxLength": 90,
          "description": "Supply Chain",
          "meetingLocation": "New York"
        }
      ],
      "130pm": [
        {
          "apptWith": "Felix Henderson",
          "MaxLength": 60,
          "description": "Manufacturing",
          "meetingLocation": "San Francisco"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: haven't touched vb in decades, but i can have a crack at it. can you show us what your source json data looks like? do you want to retain the same `Id` from your source json or are you creating your own `Id` for your mongodb records? also would you be against using a mongodb driver wrapper [library](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities) to simplify things?

Comment: @RyanGunner Thank you for offering assistance. I updated my original post to show source json. I will be creating custom Ids for each appointment / appointment request based on values contained therein. I would not be against using a mongodb driver wrapper library per se, but I would prefer not to so that I can better learn going forward. Again, thank you for any assistance you can offer!

Comment: @Ryan Gunner I just noticed that you are the creator of that wrapper library. I would be happy to use it if it's a timesaver, I just would like to learn the long way as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to get the job done:

```vb
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports MongoDB.Bson
Imports MongoDB.Bson.Serialization
Imports MongoDB.Driver
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Program

    Private ReadOnly collection As IMongoCollection(Of BsonDocument) =
        New MongoClient("mongodb://localhost/").
        GetDatabase("test").
        GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("employees")

    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim docs = GetDocs()
        Dim models = New List(Of ReplaceOneModel(Of BsonDocument))()
        Dim i = 1
        While i <= docs.Length OrElse i = 10
            Dim doc = docs(i - 1)
            Sanitize(doc)
            doc.Add("_id", "x" & i.ToString()) 'make sure to generate the same id everytime for upsert to work
            Dim upsert = New ReplaceOneModel(Of BsonDocument)(
                filter:=Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.Eq(Of String)("_id", doc.GetValue("_id")),
                replacement:=doc) With {.IsUpsert = True}
            models.Add(upsert)
            i += 1
        End While
        collection.BulkWrite(models)
    End Sub

    Private Function GetDocs() As BsonDocument()
        Using client = New HttpClient()
            Dim json = client.GetStringAsync("https://pastebin.com/raw/QtMquCps").GetAwaiter().GetResult()
            Return BsonSerializer.Deserialize(Of BsonArray)(json).[Select](Function(p) p.AsBsonDocument).ToArray()
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Sub Sanitize(ByRef doc As BsonDocument)
        doc = BsonDocument.Parse(
                Regex.Replace(
                    doc.ToString(),
                    """\w+\.\w+""\s*:",
                    Function(m) m.Value.Replace(".", ":")))
    End Sub
End Module
```

on a sidenote, having to write this vb code makes me appreciate c# so much more now :-)

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful. However, if the source data contains a period (for example, https://pastebin.com/raw/QtMquCps notice the time has a period in it), mongo seems to throw an error because it's a reserved character. How would you replace the period with another character (let's say : or -) before upserting? I noticed the same issue arises if the string begins with $, which I would imagine is a major issue for many folks storing currency values.

Comment: @Orson you can use regex for that. here's a c# example: `json = Regex.Replace(json, @"\.(?=[^""]*"":)", ":");`

Comment: Regex for the entire document wouldn't be very useful, however, because I wouldn't want to indiscriminately replace the entire document. Ideally I would like to either iterate through each field (I realize performance will suffer) or find some other way to have more granular control over each key/value. I'm starting to wonder if MongoDB is even my best option. I need to process large amounts of JSON and I didnt realize that SQL Server has some built in functions  which make it very easy compared to MongoDB (for me at least). Still evaluating the pros/cons of each. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Orson i added a `Sanitize()` method to my answer. it only adds milliseconds per document. give it a shot with large amounts of data and see how it goes.